# Know which checkbox was checked

Tags: vba, excel

I have so many checkboxes in my Excel Sheet. I am calling a Common Sub on the check event of each of them.

Is it possible to know which checkbox was check in the common Sub? (so that I
can take corresponding action)

Comment: How are you calling your sub? From an event, or just "from time to time to see what was clicked"?

Comment: Have you tried to MsgBox `Application.Caller`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub CommonClick
    Dim cb As CheckBox

    On Error Resume Next
    Set cb = ActiveSheet.Checkboxes(Application.Caller)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Sub not called from a CheckBox on current sheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    MsgBox cb.Name & " was set to " & cb.Value
End Sub
```